# Изменение переменной при взаимодействии с поиском в AppBar

Tags: android, search, toolbar

У меня есть поиск в AppBar. Мне нужно изменять переменную при его раскрытии в при сворачивании. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это реализовать.

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


   SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);




    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.korzz:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, kart.class));
            return true;
        case  R.id.app_bar_search:
            //?????



           return true;




        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="0"


    android:title="Поиск"

    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always">

</item>
<group >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/korzz"
        android:icon="@drawable/btaddcart"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Корзина"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</group>
```

Comment: Вы хоть код покажите куда вставить пытаетесь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в onCreateOptionsMenu  searchView.setOnCloseListener и searchView.setOnSearchClickListener
Всё оказалось просто.